# PHP Array Filter Multi Level

Tags: php

```
$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 7;
$users[0]['username'] = 'coin';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'XXXX';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 1;
$users[1]['id'] = 8;
$users[1]['username'] = 'asdasd';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'AAAA';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 2;
```

I want to get the room value of the member whose socket value is `AAAA`.

With Array filter I can do it when there is only one depth, but I am stuck at multiple depths.

I'd appreciate it if you could offer something other than foreach. Thanks.

The following attempt is unsuccessful.

```
$socket = 'AAAA';
$room_detect = array_filter($users, function($v, $k) use ($socket) {
if(array_search($socket, $v['rooms']))
{
    return $v;
}
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I did not understand your question. But I want to find out which room the specified socket belongs to.

Comment: What code have you tried to achieve what you want to do ? You also said _"With Array filter I can do it when there is only one depth, but I am stuck at multiple depths"_, show us that code, so we can understand more what you are trying to do, learn [ask].

Comment: @matiaslauriti Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: array_filter - you were very close in your attempt. I added array_merge to flatten the array_column and simplified your logic a bit

```
<?php    
$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 7;
$users[0]['username'] = 'coin';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'XXXX';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 1;
$users[1]['id'] = 8;
$users[1]['username'] = 'asdasd';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'AAAA';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 2;
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['socket'] = 'BBBB';
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['room'] = 4;

$socket = 'AAAA';
$room_detect = array_filter(array_merge(...array_column($users,'rooms')), function($v, $k) use ($socket) 
{ return $v['socket']===$socket;} , ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($room_detect);
```

Example: https://www.tehplayground.com/KVK1Ur0KTJYn0H3L

---

Option 2: a hack - but if you have a zillion users in that array, this might be the fastest. I'll probably get into trouble but:

```
<?php
// example code

$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 7;
$users[0]['username'] = 'coin';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'XXXX';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 1;
$users[1]['id'] = 8;
$users[1]['username'] = 'asdasd';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'AAAA';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 2;


function getRoomOf($user, $u) {
   return preg_replace('/\D/', '', explode('"room":',explode('"'.$user.'"', $u)[1])[1]);
}
print_r(getRoomOf('AAAA', json_encode($users)));
```

Example at: https://www.tehplayground.com/zpsDkRkPCEAXmQpY

Comment: It's an interesting method, but I don't think it's safe.

`$room_detect = array_filter(array_column($users,'rooms'), function($v, $k) use ($socket) 
{
 foreach($v as $room)
 {
  if($room['socket']===$socket)
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($room_detect);`

This works, but returns the rooms of the member with that socket.
My goal is to return the room number.

Comment: Can you do this if you did?. :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're searching for the room number of a given user, this will get it. And it has boundries on the name so it won't find a partial...

Comment: Can you check my answer and help?

Comment: I updated my answer with a tweak to your filter and a link to test

Answer (score 1):

You can adopt a recursive approach to make it work for any depth.

- Loop over the current level of the array.
- If the key in the current loop at hand is a `socket` and it matches the value you
  are searching for, access the `room` key instantly and return the value.
- If you can't find the socket at all, return `false`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function findSocket($data,$socket_value){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $res = findSocket($value,$socket_value);
            if($res !== false) return $res;
        }else if($key == 'socket' && $value === $socket_value){
            return $data['room']; // because socket and room keys are on the same level
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}

$room_no = findSocket($users,'AAAA');
if($room_no == false){
    die("Room not found");
}

echo $room_no;
```

Comment: Can you check my answer and help?

Comment: @CoinAnalyzer do you want room no. or array?

Comment: I just want the room number.

Comment: I'm aware :) Well, I'm wondering how this is done with array_filter. I have performance concerns. Which one do you think it should be? Thank you for your time, I look forward to your reply.

Comment: @CoinAnalyzer My code would be efficient considering the fact that `socket` could exist at any level in the nested array. You can try for large datasets and let me know if this gets inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = array();
$users[0]['id'] = 7;
$users[0]['username'] = 'coin';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'XXXX';
$users[0]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 1;
$users[1]['id'] = 8;
$users[1]['username'] = 'asdasd';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['socket'] = 'AAAA';
$users[1]['rooms'][0]['room'] = 2;
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['socket'] = 'BBBB';
$users[1]['rooms'][1]['room'] = 4;

$socket = 'AAAA';
$room_detect = array_filter(array_column($users,'rooms'), function($v, $k) use ($socket) 
{
    foreach($v as $room)
    {
        if($room['socket']===$socket)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
print_r($room_detect);
```

RESULT

```
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [socket] => AAAA
                    [room] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [socket] => BBBB
                    [room] => 4
                )

        )

)
```

I want it as below.

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [socket] => AAAA
                    [room] => 2
                )
```